# k-options with Kendo for Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

In older versions of Kendo with Angular, I was able to use a `k-options` attribute so that my controls could be configured in code as much as possible

```
<input kendo-date-picker k-options="monthPickerConfig">
```

Is something similar possible when using `Kendo UI for Angular`?  I'm not seeing anything in the samples or documentation, but have to believe that something similar exists?

In any application beyond just a small scope, it would seem to be much easier to do this

```
<kendo-slider [someProperty]="sliderConfig" />
```

Than to do this

```
<kendo-slider
  [fixedTickWidth]="10"
  [min]="min"
  [max]="max"
  [smallStep]="smallStep"
  [(ngModel)] = "valueHorizontal">
</kendo-slider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is **NO**.

This is due to the fact that kendoUI uses individual variable to handle the configuration as you see in their code. There is no way to configure an object with **`kendo-slider.`**

However if you don't want to maintain multiple variables, you can create a config object and bind them like below,

```
 <kendo-slider
        #slider
        [min]="config.min"
        [max]="config.max"
        [showButtons]="config.showButtons"
        [smallStep]="config.smallStep"
        [vertical] = "config.vertical"
        [formControlName]="id"
        (valueChange)="valueChange($event)">
 </kendo-slider>
```

Comment: Does this remain true for more complicated objects like grids, autocompletes, etc?  Each property needs to assigned individually in the markup?

Comment: yes it remains the same for them as well, you could read their documentation https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/